# C# change non unicode language or change location

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I send some text words to my client on the socket. This is only text. But sometimes I have problem. When my some client get my sended text on the socket. They saw this text incorrect.Incorrect meaning of nonUnicode level. They have problem (İ,Ö,Ü,Ğ) like this turkish character so they didnt get my text. When I change this users location information to((on region and language->administrative->Change system locale = Turkey (on windows 7))or(change non unicode language = turkish)) problem gone.

How can I fix this problem. I read some article for this, it said to you cant change this on the code behinde.so How can I create a sloution for this problem.

Thank you very much
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send the string via the socket how are you converting it to bytes and how is the receiver converting those bytes back into a string? The problem that you're experiencing is that the character encoding being used at the sender doesn't match that of the receiver. What you should be doing when converting the string into bytes is use one of the built-in Encoding classes such as `UTF8Encoding`

```
var str = ...; //whatever needs to be sent via socket    
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
var bytes = utf8.GetBytes(str);
socket.Send(bytes)
```

You'll probably want to read the input in chunks into a buffer and send it over the socket from there, but that's the general idea. The receiver at the other end should use the same encoding to convert the `byte`s received back into a `string`.

[See this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx) for more information on Encodings.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the CultureInfo of your current thread like this:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

(Don't forget to do this for every new thread)

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCultureInfo("tr-TR");      
  
I try this. This only change system dateTime format etc. this isnt enough for my code.problem continue